# Counting Postive and Negative words in a file using dictionaries (Java)

Tags: java, parsing, dictionary, compare

I'm trying to determine the number of occurrences positive and negative words in a file to calculate whether the file has a positive or a negative tone.

I'm currently having issues trying to parse a file for the number of positive and negative words contained in the file. At the moment, I'm currently using a `BufferedReader` to read the main file I'm trying to determine the positive and negative words from as well as the two files containing the dictionary of positive and negative words. However the problem I'm having is its comparing each word with the corresponding word number in the positive and negative files.

Here is my current code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class ParseTest {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
    File file1 = new File("fileforparsing");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file1)));
    File file2 = new File("positivewordsdictionary");
    BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file2)));

    int positive = 0;
           Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(br);
           Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(br1);
            while (sc1.hasNext() && sc2.hasNext()) {
                String str1 = sc1.next();
                String str2 = sc2.next();
                if (str1.equals(str2))
                    positive = positive +1;
            }
            while (sc2.hasNext())
                System.out.println(positive);
            sc1.close();
            sc2.close();
    }

}
```

I know whats wrong whereby the `scanner` is just constantly moving to the next line when I'd like the original file to stay on the same line until it has finished parsing it against the dictionary but I'm not really sure how to make it do what I want. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't work. You would need to reopen the dictionary file every time. The other thing is that it will be awfully slow. If the dictionaries are not too large, you should load them in memory and then do a read only on the file you're trying to analyze.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    Set<String> positive = loadDictionary("positivewordsdictionary");
    Set<String> negative = loadDictionary("negativewordsdictionary");

    File file = new File("fileforparsing");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file)));

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(br);
    String word;
    long positiveCount = 0;
    long negativeCount = 0;
    while (sc.hasNext()) {
        word = sc.next();
        if (positive.contains(word)) {
            System.out.println("Found positive "+positiveCount+":"+word);
            positiveCount++;
        }
        if (negative.contains(word)) {
            System.out.println("Found negative "+positiveCount+":"+word);
            negativeCount++;
        }
    }
    br.close();
}


public static Set<String> loadDictionary(String fileName) throws IOException {
    Set<String> words = new HashSet<String>();
    File file = new File(fileName);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file)));
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(br);
    while (sc.hasNext()) {
        words.add(sc.next());
    }
    br.close();
    return words;
}
```

Update: I've tried running the code and it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Bad approach.. Dont open 2 files simultaneously... First open your positive words file.. Take data out and store it as keys in a Map. Now, do the same for negative words file... Now start reading the file line by line and check if the read String contains positive/negative word.. if yes, increase the count (value of map. initialize values to 0 at the beginning.)

Answer (score 0):

Consider filling a Set (eg. HashSet) with the positive words at the start of your application.
You can use your scanner in a loop to do this:

```
while(sc2.hasNext()) {
    set.add(sc2.next());
}
```

Then, when you are looping through the other file, you can just check the set to see if it contains the word:

```
while(sc1.hasNext()) {
    if (set.contains(sc1.next()) {
        positive++;
    }
}
```